# What is default setHTTPMethod for NSURLRequest? Is it "POST" or "GET"?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

If I didn't mentioned `setHTTPMethod` for my `NSURLRequest` what will be default "POST" or "GET".

Thanks.

Comment: always the default HTTP method is `GET`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because RTFM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `HTTP method` is `GET`.

Refer this [NSURLRequest Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLRequest/HTTPMethod)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1413030-httpmethod?language=objc